# Passport req.isAuthenticated() always false when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, passport-local, passport.js

I'm using `passport` with `Nodejs`. My application works as expected when I run on my localhost. When I deploy to Heroku, however, I find that the `req.isAthenticated()` function returns false when it should return true even though passport is finding and verifying the user and password. Here is my code which initialises `express-session` and `passport`:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'foo',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 3600000
    //maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
  }
}));

app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

Here is how I define the local passport:

```
module.exports = function(passport, configIds) {
    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
        function(req, email, password, cb) {
            //console.log('got email pwd: ' + email + ' ' + password);
        User.getByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { 
                console.log('something went wrong in login strategy getting user: ' + err);
                return cb(err); 
            }
            if (!user) { 
                console.log('problem with user in local strategy');
                return cb(null, false, { message: 'cannot locate user'}); 
            }
            if (!User.comparePassword(user, password)) { 
            console.log('incorrect password for user');
                return cb(null, false, { message: 'incorrect email or password'}); 
            }
          console.log('success: return the user');
            return cb(null, user);
        });
        }
    )),
```

I'm reaching the `success: return the user` console output and once again, the `req.isAuthenticated()` function returns true, as expected, when I run on the localhost. I saw some comments about using https but I'm using secure sockets on both on localhost and Heroku. Here is the middleware I've defined that checks to see if the request is authenticated...

```
// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
        //return res.redirect('/');
        console.log('User not authenticated. Redirect to home');
        return res.status(401).redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**edit:** 
I have also checked which cookies are being stored. I can see that when running as localhost a session cookie is being stored but running from Heroku no cookie exists.

Can anyone suggest why this would work, running on localhost but break when running on Heroku?

Comment: I don't know how Heroku works exactly, but you're not using a persistent storage for `express-session` which means that if your app is served by different instances they won't share the same session storage.

Comment: thanks for the input, I'll look into that. For now I've only installed to a single node (using the free tier)..makes me think there could be another problem?

Comment: Possibly, yes. You should check and see if the frontend is receiving a session cookie after logging in, and if subsequent requests to the server send along that cookie. FWIW, with "secure sockets" you mean you're using HTTPS, correct?

Comment: That's right. I'm using HTTPS on both local and Heroku. Thanks again..

Comment: I can't see a cookie being stored after logging in when I'm on heroku, but I can see it when I run as localhost.

Comment: That might be worthwhile to mention in your question. It might be something specific to Heroku, I don't know :(

Comment: I'll edit the question, thankyou!

Comment: Hi, It's very possible that Heroku is running behind a proxy, so your express instance can't set the secure cookie. You will have to tell Express to trust proxy: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Comment: @theprogrammer good point!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @theprogrammer. I tried setting 'trust proxy' to true but the problem still persists. No cookie is being stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this works now and seems to have been because the proxy configuration was not set up properly, as suggested by theprogrammer in one of the comments (thanks!). See the amended code below that fixed the problem...

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.enable('trust proxy'); // add this line
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  proxy: true, // add this line
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 3600000,
    store: new MongoStore({ url: config.DB_URL })
  }
}));
```

I also added a MongoStore to save the session as suggested by robertklep. Hope this is of help to anyone facing the same problem.